# error when click add to cart in magento 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento, error-handling

I am new in magento.i upload my madento site about 2 months ago but now suddenly when i add a product to cart give me this error

> Cannot send headers; headers already sent in
>   /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrateuk.php,
>   line 1

Trace:

```
#0 /home/roblixsh/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(107): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://www.robl...', 302)
#2 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(711): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://www.robl...')
#3 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(689): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('checkout/cart', Array)
#4 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('checkout/cart')
#5 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(260): Mage_Checkout_CartController->_goBack()
#6 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#7 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#8 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/roblixsh/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/roblixsh/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

how can i fixed this?

Comment: Have you installed any third party module recently? Or made any custom template? Your error comes the fact something is output to screen before Magento set the page headers, which *isn't* normal behaviour. So temporarily turn off all your custom modules, and check if this is still happening

Comment: i install a extension seo suite ans product match about 3 days ago but worked until yesterday

Comment: Are you actively developing on the site? You didn't add some text at the top of a class by mistake? I would replace the `app/code/core` folder with a fresh install to make sure. (core files shouldn't be edited anyway)

Comment: but when i login in magento with a customer account give me error

Comment: yes.please can you check my site

Comment: some time work perfect and some time give error....

Comment: This generally happens when you have content in a php file before the opening <?php tag, probably placed by accident while editing the file. If you open up the files in the module you disabled you'll probably find one with this error before the opening tag.

Comment: Matt O I checked my code but dont exist  any problem on it.and my code was worked perfectly until 1 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why give error on my add to cart but finally i found issue.i write a module with Flatrateuk name and after 3 months this module occur error on my site. now i disable this module and problem solved